# Remover aspas nas linhas do arquivo csv

Tags: python

Dado um determinado arquivo iris.csv:

```
"sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species"
"5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,setosa"
"4.9,3,1.4,0.2,setosa"
"4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,setosa"
"4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,setosa"
```

Tento carregar o arquivo com o seguinte código:

```
import os
import numpy as np 
filename = os.path.join('iris.csv')
arquivo = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=',', usecols=(0,1,2,3), skiprows=1)
```

Erro retornado: could not convert string to float: '"5.1'

Tento remover as aspas duplas com o código abaixo, entretanto o erro persiste:

```
input_fd = open('iris.csv', 'r')
output_fd = open('saida.csv', 'w')
for line in input_fd.readlines():
    line = ','.join(['%s'%field.strip() for field in line.split(';')])+'\n'
    output_fd.write(line)
input_fd.close()
output_fd.close()
iris = open('saida.csv', 'r')
```

Então, como posso automatizar a retirada das aspas entre as linhas do arquivo .csv?

Comment: Se o seu arquivo está realmente asism, com aspas em torno da linha toda, o arquivo está incorreto - nenhuma função pronta vai poder ler o arquivo - respondo abaixo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o seu arquivo está realmente asism, com aspas em torno da linha toda, o arquivo está incorreto - nenhuma função pronta vai poder ler o arquivo - 
O correto para um arquivo CSV é ter apenas os valores, delimitados por um separador, e opcionalmente aspas delimitando o "conteúdo" das  células - ou seja,
uma linha poderia ser assim:

```
"5.1", "3.5" , "1.4", "0.2", "setosa"
```

Mas se está assim, a tendencia será que os interpretadores que vão ler esse arquivo vão interpretar cada linha como uma única célula:

```
"5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,setosa"
```

O ideal aí seria arrumar o que quer que esteja gerando esse arquivo para que ele seja corrigido -sem as aspas em volta de cada linha.

Em não sendo possível, seria possível criar com Python avançado algo que "finge" ser o arquivo, mas remove as '"' de cada linha, e passa a linha já sem esses caracteres para os leitores. Mas tendo em vista que ess tipo de arquivo vai ser algo casual, até o problema no gerador ser resolvido, o melhor mesmo é usar umas poucas linhas de Python básico para gravar um *outro* arquivo, arrumado - e usar os métodos normais de leitura.

O método `strip` de strings é suficiente para remvover aspas no inicio e no final 
de uma string. Mas temos que lembrar que ao ler as linhas, o último caractere é sempre o "\n" - então incluimos esse caractere na chamada ao strip.

Note que esse código vai *quebrar* um arquivo que esteja corretamente colocando aspas em cada célula:

```
def arruma_aspas(nome_do_arquivo):
   with open(nome_do_arquivo) as entrada, open(nome_do_arquivo + ".tmp", "wt") as saida:
       for linha in entrada:
           saida.write(linha.strip('"\n' + '\n')

   return nome_do_arquivo + ".tmp"
```

Comment: Na verdade, as linhas estão assim: "'5.1','3.5','1.4','0.2','setosa", o que faz o python interpretar o primeiro e último elemento como string. Quando uso  loaded_csv = np.genfromtxt('iris.csv', delimiter=','), a saída é [nan 3.5 1.4 0.2 nan]

Comment: então fic a sugestão de usar o Pandas. O código acima, de pré-processar o arquivo pode ser usado para remover as aspas também - mas principametne se você vai precisar do dado-string da última coluna, vai precisar do Pandas de qualquer forma.

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma função no numpy que seria idela pra esse caso:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
loaded_csv = genfromtxt('iris.csv', delimiter=',')
```

Ou ainda, utilizar outra biblioteca, como pandas, que possui função específica para carregar arquivos csv.

Manual: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

Comment: A saída da primeira linha loaded_csv: [nan 3.5 1.4 0.2 nan]

Comment: Sim - o numpy trabalha com arrays de dados homogêneos - se você quer trabalhar com números, o que não é número ele usa o valor "NaN": "not a number". Se quiser uma tabela com colunas híbridas, em que algumas colunas são texto e outras numéricas, você deve usar o Pandas, como o indicado - o objeto fundamental do Pandas - o "DataFrame" que é criado com a função "read_csv", pode ter colunas com tipos de dados distintos, como uma planilha.

Answer (score -1):

pode-se usar o .replace("\"", "")

Ex:

```
palavra = "\"teste\""
out = "teste"
palavra.replace("\"", "")
out = teste
```

Comment: O replace não vai funcionar no caso, por que ele está usando a chamda ao numpy para ler as linhas e já processa-as - o programa do autor da pergunta não tem acesso às strings entre elas serem lidas e o numpy tentar decodificar os dados na mesma.  
(perdão pelo downvote, o conceito estaria correto se não fosse por isso)

Comment: Entendi seu ponto, o type do objeto não é string para fazer a manipulação e também pesquisei sobre o que é o downvote, ja me conscientizei de 2 coisas.